# VS 2022 как добавить System.Managment

Tags: c#

Я хочу сделать приложения на C#, для этого мне надо библиотека System.Managment
Но его нету вот скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: когда пишу using System.Managment то он выдает ошибку, сказали что через ссылку, но его там нет на скрине видно

Comment: Версия дотнета какая?

Comment: Не пишите VS 2022, это не говорит вообще о чем-либо. Это как вон фотошоп, что в старой версии вы нарисовали картинку, что в новой, картинка будет одна, а инструменты будут отличаться лишь функционалом. Также и тут, вы можете создать, например .NET Framework проект и разрабатывать его хоть в стурии 15 года, а можете в студии 22 года, разницы для самого проекта не будет. А вот что важно, так это **тип проекта**, ибо их как минимум 2: .NET Framework и просто .NET. Вот если у вас первый тип (устаревший). то там добавление ссылок так работает, ну а во втором типе, все пакеты перенесены в NuGet.

Comment: Например вот нужный вам [System.Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для .NET Core и новее (.NET 5/6/7) надо [установить](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio) NuGet пакет [System.Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/) через меню Visual Studio.

Добавление ссылок работает только в устаревшем .NET Framework 4.x и старше.